# How to store data within app?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I currently have 2500 records which each contain the name of a location and the longitude and latitude for that location (well easting/northing but that's a different problem all together). I have this in either XML(30mb) or CSV(22mb) format.

I'm trying to understand the best way to store this data within the app, the options seem to be:

1. Include the XML/CSV file as a resource in the project and load it into an NSDictionary on initial launch of the app. Is this dataset too large for an NSDictionary and if not how would this then remain persistent rather than having to do this process each time the app launches?
2. Load the data into a core data database and include the pre-populated database as a project resource.

I'm sure this type of situation is nothing new I'm just not sure what would be considered 'best practice'.

Comment: Use a plist instead of XML or CSV. It will load into an `NSDictionary` much more efficiently.

Comment: How is a three column CSV file with 2,500 records so large? At 22MB that is 8,800 bytes per record. That's insane for a name, latitude, and longitude. Are you sure you don't mean 250,000 records or is the file really 220kB?

Comment: Depends on how you use this data. If you don't need all records at the same time you should probably use a database.

Comment: Thanks guys! No idea how it's so large, there are a few other bits in there, like modification dates but I can strip out everything I don't need to perhaps get the file size down. The app basically calculates distances between two selected locations from the data. So we're saying load it into a Plist then load it into an NSDictionary at runtime?

Comment: Not if it really is 22MB. That will waste way too much memory to have loaded all of the time. A sqlite database would be the most efficient if you just need to look up a few records at a time.